# express the symbol \ as a string

Tags: java, string

I am writing a program that scans the path of a file and remove the name of the file so that i can create a new file in that file location. To do that i decided to do something like this

```
public String outPutPath(String path) {
        String returnPath;
        for(int i=path.length()-2; i>=0;i--) {
            if(String.toChar(path.charAt(i))=="\" && path.charAt(i-1)=="\") {
                int tempt=i;
                break;
            }
        }       
        returnPath=path.subString(0,i+1)+"test";
        return returnPath;
    }
```

However i keep getting the "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"for the "\" part
Its almost as if i cant express \ as a string
i also tried to assign \ to a string variable but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to prefix it with another `\`

```
public String outPutPath(String path) {
    String returnPath;
    for(int i=path.length()-2; i>=0;i--) {
        if(String.toChar(path.charAt(i))=='\\' && path.charAt(i-1)=='\\') {
            int tempt=i;
            break;
        }
    }       
    returnPath=path.subString(0,i+1)+"test";
    return returnPath;
}
```

Comment: with the single quote not, i've missed to tell you, sorry.. however if i run this `System.out.println("\\".length());` it prints 1, the problem is that `'\\'` is a char and `"\\"` is a string, and `charAt()` return a char, and so you should check equality with a char, and so you should use the single quote

Comment: oh thanx that fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

Instead of escaping `\` (which is one possible option), I would urge you to use
[`File.separatorChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) instead; that way your code isn't tied to one platform.

```
if (path.charAt(i) == File.separatorChar && path.charAt(i - 1) == File.separatorChar) {
    int tempt = i;
    break;
}
```